# C# Generics won't allow Delegate Type Constraints

Tags: c#, generics, events, delegates, constraints

Is it possible to define a class in C# such that

```
class GenericCollection<T> : SomeBaseCollection<T> where T : Delegate
```

I couldn't for the life of me accomplish this last night in .NET 3.5. I tried using

`delegate, Delegate, Action<T> and Func<T, T>`

It seems to me that this should be allowable in some way. I'm trying to implement my own EventQueue.

I ended up just doing this [primitive approximation mind you].

```
internal delegate void DWork();

class EventQueue {
    private Queue<DWork> eventq;
}
```

But then I lose the ability to reuse the same definition for different types of functions.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A number of classes are unavailable as generic contraints - Enum being another.

For delegates, the closest you can get is ": class", perhaps using reflection to check (for example, in the static constructor) that the T *is* a delegate:

```
static GenericCollection()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T).Name + " is not a delegate type");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for: 1) using the static constructor and 2) including a detailed message due to weird debugging conditions surrounding type initialization.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Doesn't throwing an exception in a static initializer violate `CA1065: Do not raise exceptions in unexpected locations` ... I was always under the assumption that you should use a custom code analysis rule to find invalid usages of your class that aren't normally available at run-time.

Comment: Starting in C# 7.3 (released May 2018), it is allowed to constrain like this, `where T : Delegate`, (and someone posted a new answer about that below).

Answer (score 21):

Yes it's possible in C# 7.3, Constraints family increased to include `Enum`, `Delegate` and `unmanaged` types.
You can write this code without a problem:

```
void M<D, E, T>(D d, E e, T* t) where D : Delegate where E : Enum where T : unmanaged
    {

    }
```

[From Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#unmanaged-constraint):

> Beginning with C# 7.3, you can use the unmanaged constraint to specify
> that the type parameter must be a non-nullable unmanaged type. The
> unmanaged constraint enables you to write reusable routines to work
> with types that can be manipulated as blocks of memory

Useful links:

[The future of C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ0rWLaMZeI&t=650s), from Microsoft Build 2018

[What's new in C# 7.3?](https://dev.to/borrrden/whats-new-in-c-73-26fk)

Comment: Yes, it is possible in C# 7.3 (since May 2018), and you can see [release notes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#csharp).

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer, the current one is from 2008.. Very outdated now.

Comment: So you can use `Delegate`, meaning "any function" - but there is still no way to constrain a type parameter to a specific `delegate` type? When would anyone want `Delegate` without specifying the parameters and return-type? Doesn't seem useful.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:** Some proposed work-arounds are proposed in these articles:

http://jacobcarpenters.blogspot.com/2006/06/c-30-and-delegate-conversion.html

http://jacobcarpenters.blogspot.com/2006_11_01_archive.html

---

From the [C# 2.0 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/f/98fdf0c7-2bbd-40d3-9fd1-5a4159fa8044/CSharp%202.0%20Specification_Sept_2005.doc) we can read (20.7, Constraints):

A class-type constraint must satisfy the following rules:

- The type must be a class type.
- The type must not be sealed.
- **The type must not be one of the following types: System.Array, System.Delegate, System.Enum, or System.ValueType**.
- The type must not be object. Because all types derive from object, such a constraint would have no effect if it were permitted.
- At most one constraint for a given type parameter can be a class type.

And sure enough VS2008 spits out an error:

```
error CS0702: Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Delegate'
```

For info and investigation on this issue read [here](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/mike/archive/2005/12/06/17307.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

If you are willing to take a compile time dependency on an IL Weaver you can do this with [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody).

Using this addin to Fody https://github.com/Fody/ExtraConstraints

**Your code can look like this**

```
public class Sample
{
    public void MethodWithDelegateConstraint<[DelegateConstraint] T> ()
    {        
    }
    public void MethodWithEnumConstraint<[EnumConstraint] T>()
    {
    }
}
```

**And be compiled to this**

```
public class Sample
{
    public void MethodWithDelegateConstraint<T>() where T: Delegate
    {
    }

    public void MethodWithEnumConstraint<T>() where T: struct, Enum
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Broken link. Do you have a current one?

Answer (score 4):

I came across a situation where I needed to deal with a `Delegate` internally but I wanted a generic constraint. Specifically, I wanted to add an event handler using reflection, but I wanted to use a generic argument for the delegate. The code below does NOT work, since "Handler" is a type variable, and the compiler won't cast `Handler` to `Delegate`:

```
public void AddHandler<Handler>(Control c, string eventName, Handler d) {
  c.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).AddEventHandler(c, (Delegate) d);
}
```

However, you can pass a function that does the conversion for you. `convert` takes a `Handler` argument and returns a `Delegate`:

```
public void AddHandler<Handler>(Control c, string eventName, 
                  Func<Delegate, Handler> convert, Handler d) {
      c.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).AddEventHandler(c, convert(d));
}
```

Now the compiler is happy. Calling the method is easy. For example, attaching to the `KeyPress` event on a Windows Forms control:

```
AddHandler<KeyEventHandler>(someControl, 
           "KeyPress", 
           (h) => (KeyEventHandler) h,
           SomeControl_KeyPress);
```

where `SomeControl_KeyPress` is the event target. The key is the converter lambda - it does no work, but it convinces the compiler you gave it a valid delegate.

(Begin 280Z28) @Justin: Why not use this?

```
public void AddHandler<Handler>(Control c, string eventName, Handler d) { 
  c.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).AddEventHandler(c, d as Delegate); 
}
```

(End 280Z28)

Comment: @Justin: I edited your answer to put my comment at the end since it has a code block.

Answer (score 3):

Delegate already supports chaining.  Doesn't this meet your needs?

```
public class EventQueueTests
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        Action myAction = () => Console.WriteLine("foo");
        myAction += () => Console.WriteLine("bar");

        myAction();
        //foo
        //bar
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        Action<int> myAction = x => Console.WriteLine("foo {0}", x);
        myAction += x => Console.WriteLine("bar {0}", x);
        myAction(3);
        //foo 3
        //bar 3
    }

    public void Test3()
    {
        Func<int, int> myFunc = x => { Console.WriteLine("foo {0}", x); return x + 2; };
        myFunc += x => { Console.WriteLine("bar {0}", x); return x + 1; };
        int y = myFunc(3);
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        //foo 3
        //bar 3
        //4
    }

    public void Test4()
    {
        Func<int, int> myFunc = x => { Console.WriteLine("foo {0}", x); return x + 2; };
        Func<int, int> myNextFunc = x => { x = myFunc(x);  Console.WriteLine("bar {0}", x); return x + 1; };
        int y = myNextFunc(3);
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        //foo 3
        //bar 5
        //6
    }

}
```

Comment: thats not really the functionality i'm looking for...

I was trying to make a type constraint on my generic class...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you cannot have Delegates and Enum as a generic constraint. `System.Object` and `System.ValueType` also cannot be used as a generic constraint.

The work around can be if you construct an appropriate call in you IL. It will work fine.

Here is a good example by Jon Skeet.

http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

I have taken my references from Jon Skeet's book *C# in Depth*, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56b2hk61.aspx)

**Compiler Error CS0702**

Constraint cannot be special class 'identifier' The following types may not be used as constraints:

- System.Object
- System.Array
- System.Delegate
- System.Enum
- System.ValueType.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question here? You don't tell us anything new.