# Making a generic type constraint on Func<T>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I wanted to know if this is possible:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Func<T>
```

or

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Func<>
```

It seems like the compiler is telling me it not possible. I suppose I can throw a runtime exception in the constructor, but was hoping to have it a compiler error.

Any ways about doing this?

Comment: Probably the proper solution here is to just accept `T`, then use `Func<T>` in your class.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I'd have to go like the .NET folks create 17 overloads to support the base Func<T .... T16> case. :) I know it's silly, just wanting to know.

Comment: Not saying this is a good idea but you could follow this https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543871 thread and make a change in Roslyn and compile your code using that compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you are out of luck. `Func<>` and `Action<>` are both delegate types, which cannot be used as a generic type constraint.

This answer sums it up pretty well
[C# Generics won't allow Delegate Type Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191940/c-sharp-generics-wont-allow-delegate-type-constraints)

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer informs, you can't achieve a generic type constraint for Func<>, however C# 7.3 allows you to do a constraint like this

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Delegate
```

or

```
public class Foo<T> where T : MulticastDelegate
```

that's the closest you can get.